# Conditional mutate using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataset of locations, `To` and `From` in which only `To` has latitudes and longitudes. Here is some mock data to work with:

```
df <- data.frame(
  To = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,9),
  Latitude = c(37,37,37,37,35,34,38,38,39,39,39,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,33,33),
  Longitude = c(-75,-75,-75,-75,-75,-75,-75,-75,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-74,-73,-73),
  From = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,9,1)
)
```

I am trying to create a list of `From` `Latitude` and `Longitude` based off the values in the `To` column.

I tried to mutate as follows:

```
df %>%
  mutate(From.Lat = if_else(From == To, Latitude, NA_real_))
```

But this only works row by row (and fill down won't work either as a crude solution due to the nature of my data set).

How can I make it so that any time `From == To`, no matter the row, I duplicate `Latitude` and `Longitude` for `From`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep distinct pairs of (To, Latitude, Longitude) and merge it back to the initial data.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct(To, Latitude, Longitude) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("From" = "To"), suffix = c(".To", ".From"))

# A tibble: 21 × 6
      To Latitude.To Longitude.To  From Latitude.From Longitude.From
   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1          37          -75     1            37            -75
 2     1          37          -75     1            37            -75
 3     1          37          -75     1            37            -75
 4     1          37          -75     2            35            -75
 5     2          35          -75     2            35            -75
 6     3          34          -75     3            34            -75
# … with 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
merge(df, unique(df[1:3]), by.x = "From", by.y = "To", all.x = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 From To Latitude.x Longitude.x Latitude.y Longitude.y
1     1  1         37         -75         37         -75
2     1  1         37         -75         37         -75
3     1  1         37         -75         37         -75
4     1  9         33         -73         37         -75
5     2  1         37         -75         35         -75
6     2  2         35         -75         35         -75
7     3  3         34         -75         34         -75
8     4  4         38         -75         38         -75
9     4  5         39         -74         38         -75
10    5  4         38         -75         39         -74
11    5  5         39         -74         39         -74
12    5  6         31         -74         39         -74
13    5  5         39         -74         39         -74
14    6  7         30         -74         31         -74
15    6  7         30         -74         31         -74
16    6  7         30         -74         31         -74
17    7  7         30         -74         30         -74
18    7  7         30         -74         30         -74
19    7  7         30         -74         30         -74
20    8  8         32         -74         32         -74
21    9  9         33         -73         33         -73
```